# There are spaces in string, but I can't split it in powershell

Tags: powershell, replace, split

I want to compare user's groups and DFS's groups to find out if the user has access authority to DFS. but I got stuck in split string.

here is part of my code:

```
$folder = Read-Host 'Enter the folder path'
$User = Read-Host 'Enter the sAMAccountName of user'
$getSGs = (get-acl $folder).Access | Select-Object -uniq -ExpandProperty IdentityReference 
$getSGsSplit = $getSGs -split('.*\\')
$arr = $getSGsSplit -split ' '
Write-Host $arr
```

the value of $getSGs：

```
domain-ORG\xxx-Read domain-ORG\xxx-Modify domain-ORG\xxx-Admin domain-ORG\xxx-Center domain-ORG\xxxx-Admin BUILTIN\Administrators
```

the value of $getSGsSplit:

```
 xxx-Read  xxx-Modify  xxx-Admin  xxx-Center  xxxx-Admin  Administrators
```

What I Want is to split the $getSGsSplit by spaces:

```
xxx-Read
xxx-Modify
xxx-Admin
xxx-Center  
xxxx-Admin
BUILTIN\Administrators
```

BUT I have been tried lots of patterns, all of them doesn't work.

```
$getSGsSplit -split ' .-`t`n`r'
$getSGsSplit -replace ' ','\n'
$getSGsSplit.split(' ').trim()
$getSGsSplit.split('\s').trim()
$getSGsSplit -split ' '
```

And no matter which pattern I used , the console of `write-host $arr[2]` still were spaces. And console of `write-host $arr[2].getType()` always were System.String

```
PS C:\Users\zzz\Desktop> C:\Users\zzz\Desktop\12.ps1
Enter the folder path: \\domain.org\xxx\xx\xxx
Enter the sAMAccountName of user: zzz


PS C:\Users\zzz\Desktop>
```

Can anyone advise how to resolve this?

Comment: `($getSGsSplit -split '\s').Where({ $_ -ne '' })` . You had the good idea with your `.split` combined with the `\S`  but the .net method does not take a regex value for its `.split` argument. The Powershell `-Split` operator though does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply loop over the values returned by `Get-Acl` and replace the domain part on every item?

Something like

```
((Get-Acl $folder).Access | 
    Select-Object IdentityReference -Unique).IdentityReference | 
    ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '^domain-ORG\\' }
```

<sup>P.S.
Your code `$getSGs = (get-acl $folder).Access | Select-Object -uniq -ExpandProperty IdentityReference` does not return a **string**, but an array of **objects** with a `Value` property in which the account name is held.

Because you later use `-split('.*\\')` on it, the result becomes an array of strings, but if you simply leave that out the code can be much simpler.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Just considering the string that you already have:

Below should give you what you are looking for:

```
$a= "domain-ORG\xxx-Read domain-ORG\xxx-Modify domain-ORG\xxx-Admin domain-ORG\xxx-Center domain-ORG\xxxx-Admin BUILTIN\Administrators"

($a -split '\s').replace('domain-ORG\','')
```